# get a pagingobject in http response requested over curl

Tags: java, json, curl, embedded-linux, paging

Hello people i have a question about how to get JSON pagingObject in my response with a http curl get (curl running on jokto-linux-system).
i wanted to get a special page over the parameter $offset=0 and $limit=0.
But i dont know where to put the parameter to get on the right page of the serviceressource. I get all the ressources back but i need to see how much pages are used also i didnt see this too.
So my basic problem is the visibility and changing of the parameter $offset and $limit of the pagingObject of an Service/Ressource with amount of Ressourceelements. 
Thank you very much for evry answer

This my basic "GET" i try: curl -i http://127.0.0.1:80/service/ressource/Elementuri

Tried to get an the object over header: curl -X GET -H "$offset" -H "$limit" http://127.0.0.1:80/service/ressource/elementuri

I tried it to set after the uri:  curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:80/service/ressource/elementuri?$offset=0&$limit=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dollar sign is probably not necessary.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:80/service/ressource/elementuri?limit=2&offset=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Paging for VIWI is explained in the [VIWI specification](https://www.w3.org/Submission/viwi-protocol/#paging). Please note that special characters like the dollar sign must be escaped (see the table [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)) if the client does not do that automatically.